# grouping by count without losing columns

Tags: r, group-by, count, dplyr

I am trying to group a data by a count of a variable without losing the other columns.
The data I have is:

```
count_subways      interv
20                 1-6-2014 00:00
45                 1-6-2014 00:15
```

I am trying to group the rows by interv and count observations in every inter, while keeping the count_subways column.

I tried:

```
df1 = df %>% group_by(interv) %>% summarise(count=n())
```

and that didn't work. also I tried:

```
uber_final_1=uber_final %>% group_by(interv) %>%  mutate(uber_count=count(interv))
```

that returned an error massage:

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>   Evaluation error: no applicable method for 'groups' applied to 
>   an object of class "c('POSIXct', 'POSIXt')".

I would appreciate your help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: Please edit your question to add sample data using `dput`. You can use `dput(head(df,n))` to add sample data to your question.

Comment: Please provide a reproducible input and desired output.

Comment: You may need `mutate(count = n())`

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using toy data set

```
aggregate(warpbreaks$breaks,list(warpbreaks$wool,warpbreaks$tension),length)

  Group.1 Group.2 x
1       A       L 9
2       B       L 9
3       A       M 9
4       B       M 9
5       A       H 9
6       B       H 9
```

Comment: This is different from the question. A better way is to use data containing date-time data as in the question or ask OP for more reproducible data.

Answer (score 0):

Is this similar to your dataset, OP?

```
start <- as.POSIXct("1-6-2014 00:00", format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
finish <- as.POSIXct("1-6-2014 00:29", format = "%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")
time_seq <- seq.POSIXt(from = start, to = finish, by = 60)
df <- data.frame(
      time = time_seq,
      count_subways = sample(1:10, size = length(time_seq), replace = TRUE)      
    )
```